# "Paradox" involving Hilbert's decision problem

Tags: logic, meta-math, automated-theorem-proving

I'm currently reading "Labyrinths of Reason" by William Poundstone. My experience and ability when it comes to mathematics and formal logic is pretty limited, but the book seems to imply the following:

A) There is an algorithm that can determine whether or not a set of statements in a formal language is consistent.

B) In order to show that a statement (X) can be deduced from a given set of statements (S), it is sufficient to show that X is consistent with S, and that 'not X' is not consistent with S.

If these two are true, it would seem that there must be a solution to Hilbert's "decision problem", which is impossible.

I'm sure the problem is with my interpretation of the book and/or my reasoning, but I haven't been able to find it. Are A and/or B in fact false?

edit: The book in question contains a chapter called "a computer as big as the universe" which claims that if such a computer (with components the size of protons and switching speeds = the time it takes for light to travel the diameter of a proton, etc) started adding "beliefs" to a list one by one and checking for contradictions along the way, it would only be able to verify the consistency of around 558 beliefs in the span of a few hundred billion years. It's mentioned that "for the computer's benefit" the beliefs are encoded as logical statements about boolean unknowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B is true ... though the part about showing that X is consistent with S is unnecessary: as long as you can show that not X is inconsistent with S, then X logically follows from S.

A is false ... assuming we are talking about first-order logic there is no such algorithm ... but there *is* an algorithm that can determine that some set of first-order logic sentences is inconsistent (which, combined with B means that the algorithm will determine that some first-order X logic statement logically follows from some set S of first-orer logic statements), but this algorithm will not be able to tell all consistent sets of statements to be consistent (for some of those consistent sets, the algorithm will go into an infinite loop, so you will never know that it is consistent). Thus, we say that first-order logic is 'semi-decidable' ... But it is not (fully) decidable.

Comment: "B is true ... though the part about showing that X is consistent with S is unnecessary: as long as you can show that not X is inconsistent with S, then X logically follows from S." Good point. I see that now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that there always exists an algorithm that can determine if a set of sentences is consistent. For some formal languages, there even isn't even an algorithm that can check if a string of symbols is syntactically meaningful in that language!

Comment: Interesting! When I get home I'll have to go back and see what made me think that...

Comment: @NoahSchweber Map your alphabet to $\mathbb{N}$ via some encoding function, $f$, and then accept a string, $s$, as syntactically valid iff $f(s)\in P$ for some set $P$. Now just let $P$ be an uncomputable set.

Comment: @StellaBiderman No, I think you're right - I think "formal language" is usually used to refer to an arbitrary (not even c.e.?) set of finite strings. I misunderstood what you meant by formal language; I've deleted my incorrect comments above. (When I hear "formal language" it's in the context of abstract model theory, and specifically logics whose syntax rules are computable, so that was my reflex response.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Wikipedia says that a formal language over $\sum$ is just a subset of $\sum^*$ which would mean that it doesn't even have to be c.e. Obviously the combination rules are going to be c.e. so a non-c.e. language would have a large collection of "basic" words that form a non-c.e. set.

Comment: "Obviously the combination rules are going to be c.e." Why is that? If we're not demanding that our formal languages' syntax be computable, why are we demanding that the combination rules be c.e.? (Of course usually we only care about them when they are ...) I guess my question is, what exactly is your definition of formal language? The three uses I'm familiar with are (i) arbitrary set of finite strings, (ii) arbitrary *c.e.* set of finite strings, and (iii) computable set of finite strings corresponding in a "nice" way to the sentences of some "nice" logic (obviously, this last is informal).

Comment: @Simplex I suspect that you're thinking of the fact that in a "nice" formal language, the set of valid sentences is computably *enumerable* (or *semidecidable*). This of course requires the formal language in question to be reasonably nice.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I guess that you could have a general function of two variables be a combination rule... it would just be super not meaningful because you wouldn't be able to write them down and so a computer couldn't actually /use/ them to combine formulae. But sure, take the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ and say that $0$ is a WFF, $1$ is a WFF, and $ab$ is a WFF when the $ab^{th}$ TM halts on the input $ab$ (under some ordering of TMs such that the 0th and 1st TM halt on 0 and 1 respectively). Now $s$ is a WFF precisely when $s$ is in the Halting Problem.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Also, note that we really need to pay attention only to "nice" formal languages for the relevant claims about decidability, etc. to be meaningful - I can construct a c.e. language and a c.e. deduction system, which is "equivalent" (not computably, though) to first-order logic in whatever signature you prefer, such that the set of validities is computable. So in this case I think this level of generality in the definition of "formal language" might be misleading to the OP. (And this was motivating my own confusion earlier, to some extent.)

Comment: Actually, looking at the wikipedia page, a formal language there is defined just as any set of finite symbols over the given alphabet - no combination rule is even needed. So at that level of generality, everything interesting trivially breaks down.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If I'm being honest, I think the root of the problem is that I'm thinking in pretty vague terms about deep subjects that I really don't understand well. My formal math education goes all the way up to high school precalculus, so most of what you and Stella have been saying is way over my head for the time being. One of my biggest regrets is that I didn't discover my passion for math at an earlier age.